# even two string are same but when compare result are coming false

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am comparing two string.I am reading String 1 i.e expectedResult  from excelsheet and String 2 i.e actualResult i am getting from web page by using " getElementByXPath("errorMsg_userPass").getText();

but when i equate  two string even though they are same  result of comparison are coming false i.e they are not same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGSBb.png)

I don't know why it is happening like this .Please Help

Answer (score 0):

use `trim()` to remove leading and trailing spaces!!

Comment: He is already doing that. But I guess you mean to do that in the assertEquals part. But it wouldn't explain why he get's into that branch of code anyway (past !(actual.trim()).equals(expected.trim())).

Comment: yes and also try doing `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead equals!!

Comment: Well, what if he wanted to check the case? I would want my error messages properly spelled. Also you haven't tried to explain why would you think adding trim to assertEquals part would help.

Comment: my idea for using `trim()` is to remove any additional leading/trailing spaces both expected and actual but i'm also wondering why is to going to that  branch of code anyway  !(actual.trim()).equals(expected.trim()).

Comment: I have used trim() function in my code but ans is not coming true.I have used like if (!((actualResult.trim()).equals(expectedResult.trim()) )) {}

Comment: @DoubtClear Have you checked the exact bytes of the actual and expected strings as I suggest in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you looking at the exact bytes of the actual and expected strings. There might be for instance an unbreakable space instead of a regular space and then they will look the same but won't be the same for equals.

You can see the difference by running the following snippet:

```
String a = new String("a\u00A0b");
String b = new String ("a b");
System.out.println(a + "|" + Arrays.toString(a.getBytes()));
System.out.println(b + "|" + Arrays.toString(b.getBytes()));
```

Which will output:

```
a b|[97, -62, -96, 98]
a b|[97, 32, 98]
```

Comment: hey ,I have tried if ((actualResult.getBytes()).equals(expectedResult.getBytes()) ) {
    System.out.println("String  Equal");
    
   }     but getting the same issue.Any other solution??

Comment: I did not mean to compare bytes. You should have a look on exact bytes in the actual and expected to see how they differ. Like in the example I gave in my answer. There both strings print out as 'a b' but first contains '-62, -96' as a space since it is a non-breakable space, the second contains a usual space - '32'. Then you would see the difference and can act on it. For instance check where the non-breakable space comes from or create the 'expected' result so that it contains non-breakable space on the right place and then just compare with equals.

Comment: @DoubtClear Have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: What does it print out when you call: System.out.println(actualResult + " | " + Arrays.toString(actualResult.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(expectedResult + "|" + Arrays.toString(expectedResult.getBytes()));

Comment: @DoubtClear I would be nice if you tell us what was the problem. Or tell us what bytes are in the actual and expected result.